# Variable evaluation before assignment in awk

Tags: awk

In the following awk statement:

```
awk '$2 > maxrate {maxrate = $2; maxemp = $1} 
     END {print "highest hourly rate:", maxrate, "for", maxemp}' pay.data
```

run on the following data:

```
Beth 4.00 0
Dan 3.75 0
Kathy 4.00 10
Mark 5.00 20
Mary 5.50 22
Susie 4.25 18
```

How does `$2 > maxrate` works since it is evaluated before its assignment to `$2`?

Comment: Anything is greater than nothing. Except negative values. And zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the GNU awk [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variables)

> By default, variables are initialized to the empty string, which is
> zero if converted to a number. There is no need to explicitly
> initialize a variable in awk, which is what you would do in C and in
> most other traditional languages.

This implicit way, which usually apply for scripting languages, is very comfortable but also leaves room for mistakes or confusion.

---

For example, in this case, you can calculate the maximum, with no need to initialise `max`:

```
awk '$2 > max{max = $2} END{print "max:", max}' file
max: 5.50
```

But if you do the same for the `min` you get the empty string as result, because `min` is initially zero as a number and empty as a string.

```
awk '$2 < min{min = $2} END{print "min:", min}' file
min:
```

Also the `max` calculation could fail, if we had all values negative. So it would be better to assign something first time for sure.

```
awk 'NR==1{min=$2; next} $2<min{min = $2} END{print "min:", min}' file
min: 3.75
```

This way should work for both `min` and `max`, for numbers of any range. In general, when scripting, we have to think of all possible cases when our not defined and/or not initialised variable will be initialised. And for the cases that it will be tested before getting a value.

Answer (score 4):

By default if you dont't assign any value to a variable in `awk` then it's default value will be null(without explicitly mentioning a variable we could directly assign values to it in `awk`), so your first time condition is getting compared with null hence it's getting true and going inside block for further statements execution(where inside block it's assigning `maxrate` to 2nd field).

After very first execution when variable `maxrate` is getting 2nd field value in it then next line onwards it's comparing 1st line's 2nd field value to current line's 2nd field and keep doing the same till all lines of Input_file are read. At last in `END` section of code it print it.